# Why doesn't my Background Image Show?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting a background image to show in a div and can't for the life of me see why...

This is the structure that I have:

```
Folder
      \style.css
      \index.html
      \Images
             \bookone.jpg
```

I want the `bookone.jpg` file to be the background of a div. 
So the CSS path would be Folder/style.css and the image path is Folder/Images/bookone.jpg. I have the below code in my html and css file but I get nothing when previewing it.

```css
/* CSS */

.book {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#bookone {
  background: url(..\Images\bookone.jpg) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="bookone" class="book"></div>
```

Comment: You should use slash (/) and not backslash (\). And also - make sure the image is in the correct path (relatively to the current css/html file).

Comment: If I copy the full file path should that work?

Comment: No, because on `windows` systems the full file path uses forward-slash, and in html/css you should use a backslash (/).

Comment: AH! that makes sense. I changed it to (../Images/bookone.jpg) but still nothing shows. Any other suggestions?

Comment: where exactly this file exists and where is this css code?

Comment: So I have my projects folder. Let's call it Folder. with in that folder is style.css, index.html, and another folder called "Images" within the Images folder I have bookone.jpg. So the CSS path would be Folder/style.css and the image path is Folder/Images/bookone.jpg.

Comment: Add this information inside the question

Comment: Anyway - the `..` means "go up one folder and search for this file overthere". So in your case, if you have `c:\Folder\style.css`, and you have `url(../Images/bookone.jpg)`, what you actually say is "go find bookone.jpg in `C:\Images\bookone.jpg`", which is not what you are trying to do...

Comment: try `url(Images/bookone.jpg)` in ur css file

Comment: Ha well there ya go. just two dots is the difference from being successful and failing. Thank you so much Dekel!

Comment: `Images or images` check with your spell caps or small

Comment: Rahul It was actually @Dekel That solved it. The solution was that I was point the path up a level when the folder I wanted was in the same folder as the CSS file.

Comment: @MarkR, I'll add it as an answer with all the relevant details (from our conversation in the comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should use slash (/) and not backslash (\).
2. You should make sure the image is in the correct path (relatively to the current css/html file).
   If the images exists in the same location of your css file (or your html file) you shouldn't use the `..`, since it actually tells your browser to search for that image in the upper-folder.

This is the final css code you should probably use:

```
.book {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#bookone {
  background: url(Images/bookone.jpg) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just writing my comment as answer as this help OP to solved the problem

try `url(Images/bookone.jpg)` in ur css file

Answer (score 0):

It appears like the image you want have as a background is in another folder away from where the CSS is. I suggest you assign the background image from the HTML code. Use the forward slash (/) and not backslash (\).

E.G

```
<div id="bookone" class="book" style="background: (url('/myimage/bg.jpg')"></div>
```

or  on css

```
.book {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#bookone {
  background: url(./images/bookone.jpg) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```